# Is there an 'anytype' type for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function

Like the parameter in ISNULL function?

Something we can use to define:

```
create function getvalue
(
    @param1 varchar(max),
    @param2 varchar(max),
    @value anytype
)
return anytype

as
...
```

Comment: You could use `sql_variant` - but why would you really need this?? What's the use case, the scenario where you really truly need this??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [sql_variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx) data type.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. sql_variant is enough. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is No.  sql_variant let's you get close, but not quite.

If sql_variant isn't enough, you can overcome this by having multiple nullable parameters of all of the relevant types, but it's not pretty.